# Is there any different between input type="text" and input type="Text"?

Tags: html, forms

I came across a form like this:

```
  <input name="BuyerWizard$buyerFirstName" id="BuyerWizard_buyerFirstName" type="text" maxlength="100">

  <p class="text">E-mail Address:</p>
  <input name="BuyerWizard$buyerEmail" id="BuyerWizard$buyerEmail" onkeydown="arrowKeyNavigate(this);" type="Text" maxlength="100" value="">
```

Is there any different between the input type="text" and input type="Text"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, but lower case is cooler.

Answer (score 1):

no, html attributes are [case insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/documents.html#case-insensitivity)

Comment: Attribute names are case insensitive but the values only for certain attributes. So for certain attributes the values are indeed case sensitive `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` and `<input type="submit" value="submit">`

Answer (score 1):

Mostly browsers ignore this, but it should be lowercase [as described](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2)

Comment: This section just says that the attribute name and the tag name itself have to be lowercase `<input type=` instead of `<INPUT TYPE=`. Anyway this is about `xhtml` without knowing which `doctype` is used this part is irrelevant. How the value of an attribute has to be written depends on the attribute itself. But there is no general rule that an attribute value has to be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) there is only one attribute value for the `type` attribute called "text", so a capitalized value should be the same as the uncapitalized.

The [W3C documentation for HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-type-INPUT) states that the value for the `type` attribute is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

All the letters are converted to lowercase.
For example type="pAssword" is the same as type="password"

Answer (score 0):

Its just a **Typo**, there is no difference.  Even TEXT does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any difference but you should follow W3C standards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **HTML4** you can use both, because is case-insensitive.
But if you are using **XHTML** I think you must use lowercase, because it's case-sensitive.

[What Big Bosses has to say about that (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.11)